# SQL cast MYY varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am provided a date in myy format from a source I cannot alter. I require this to be cast to a date. Ex:

| Field | = Date |
| --- | --- |
| 905 | 2005-09-01 |
| 122 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1216 | 2016-12-01 |

I do have a method which works but I find it ugly and I'm certain there is a better way.

```
TRY_CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(NULLIF(field,''),LEN(field)-2),'/01/',RIGHT(NULLIF(field,''),2)) AS DATE)
```

Also have some issues with blank fields, hence the NULLIF() use.

Database compatibility is limited to 2008 (100).

Comment: If you have a value like 123 is that January 1923 or January 2023? How *you* know, and (more importantly) how would SQL Server?

Comment: @Larnu - I believe that SQL Server handles two-digit format so 49 is 2049 and 50 is 1950. For this specific question it IS safe to assume all values are 2000+.

Comment: SQL server does "handle" 2 digit dates, but it effectively guesses which century is correct. As the Y2K bug taught us, @Sky, storing 2 digit years is a very silly mistake.

Comment: @Larnu - Couldn't agree more. I have no control over the source, though I'll certainly be making a stink about it.

Comment: @lptr Well that works :D this should be an answer.

Comment: @lptr I would implore you to post your original dbfiddle as an answer to this question. It's certainly a much cleaner and clearer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way it gives better Result

```
select TRY_CAST(YorField as date) from YourTable
```

Sample example

```
select TRY_CAST('September 2005' as date)
```

Result: **2005-09-01**

After your edit the following gives you expected Result

```
select TRY_CAST(left('905',case when len('905')=3 then 1 else 2 end)+'.'+'01'+'.'+RIGHT('905',2) as date)
select TRY_CAST(left('122',case when len('122')=3 then 1 else 2 end)+'.'+'01'+'.'+RIGHT('122',2) as date)
select TRY_CAST(left('1216',case when len('1216')=3 then 1 else 2 end)+'.'+'01'+'.'+RIGHT('1216',2) as date)
```

Result will be

**2005-09-01,  2022-01-01,   2016-12-01**

Comment: The field contains data in MYY format, not text. Else I agree, that would work great.

Comment: give me expected Result you wanted @Sky i'll make changes accordingly

Comment: In = 422, Out = 2022-04-01 :)

Comment: @Sky Question before with date as **September 2005** later he changed. i given answer for before question

Comment: This doesn't work. *If* OP's column is an `int` (it's unclear) then you'll get the error `Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.`, if it's a `varchar` you'll get `NULL`.

Comment: The question was misleading (I'm a newb here); I only need it cast and not converted. The data type is varchar (I did pop that in the title).

Comment: `CAST` and `CONVERT` do the same thing, @Sky . `CONVERT` just allows you to specify a style when converting the value, and the syntax for the function is often RDBMS specific (where as `CAST` is an ANSI function).

Comment: @Sky changes are Made check queries once again

Comment: @Larnu new change are made check once again

Answer (score 0):

One method would be the following. Firstly I use concatenation and `RIGHT` to ensure that the value is 4 characters in length. Then I `STUFF` and concatenation to create a date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`. Next `TRY_CONVERT` is used to *attempt* to convert the date to a valid date; if it isn't valid then `NULL` will be returned. Lastly, in the `SELECT` the month's name and year are concatenated together.

```sql
SELECT D.ActualDate, --Actually a date
       CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,D.ActualDate),' ',DATEPART(YEAR, D.ActualDate)) --Meets OP's original requirement
FROM (VALUES('905'),('122'),('1216'))V(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(date,'01/' + STUFF(RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',V.YourColumn),4),3,0,'/20'),103)))D(ActualDate)
```

Though, honestly, the best thing you can do here is fix your design; don't store years as 2 digits, and a format like `Myy` is honestly *terrible*. There are several date and time data types, and you should really be using one of those for the *date* data.

Comment: My question may have been misleading. I only require the field cast to a date, not the string example I provided. I have updated the question.

Comment: Well, the above does that, @Sky . You need to just need the value of `ActualDate` instead. Likely you could move the expression in the `CROSS APPLY` to the `SELECT` too.

Comment: I appreciate that, this could be a decent way of doing it, though when I ran on the DB I've just found the Compatibility Level is not sufficient for TRY_CONVERT. It's on an older SQL Server 2008 (100). Again, not my DB and I cannot change it. It's a shame since this is SQL Server 2017.

Comment: ... That is something you should have informed us when you asked, @Sky . 2008 is *completely* unsupported (has been for 3 years), and it is *assumed* you are using supported technology when asking a question. Unfortunately, as the question's goal posts have moved twice all ready, I'm not committing more time to address another goal post move. I suggest you get that compatibility level/version updated.

Comment: I do appreciate your time on this question, especially given it's my first. However, I've been straight from the start that this is not my database and I have no control over it. I simply need to report on the data provided and this weird format isn't something I've come across before.